# linking fields in crystal reports links tab

Tags: crystal-reports

Please suggest me to get this requirement.

I have a report where I need show data wise sites.Suppose if I click on particular date it should show respected sites.
The date field is coming from different query and sites info is coming from diff query.
Now I need to pass this date field as a parameter to 2nd query.But due to some limitation(nested sub reports) I am not using sub report approach.
I am using drill down concept.

So I have taken both queries in one report only and I written a sub query in 2nd query to get 1st queries date .
Now I am displaying the date parameter in 2nd query as a column.
Now I have date columns in both the queries.
Now what is my doubt is whether I need to link both the queries date fields in links tab(As I need to show sites coming from 2nd query by clicking date field coming from 1st query)
Please suggest .

Comment: clarify me one thing here.. Different query means? query coming from different table or same table?

Comment: Hi Siva Not all same tables Some different table also there in both queries

Comment: Then instead of preparing queries, join the tables that would be easy.